# Array is shown when printed but cannot compare it with a string in php

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am trying to write a php script to confirm an email address. I am using a file instead of a database to store user info which is outside the root directory. The file is csv.

When I try to store its contents in an array and print it, it works but when I try to compare an element from the array, it doesn't work. And also I want to write the email address of the user in csv as the last entry on the same line as other info.

Please help.

```
<?php
    $rows[] = array();
    $username = $_GET["username"];
    $passkey = $_GET["passkey"];
    $userdata = fopen("/****/*********/*****/$username.csv", "r");
    $email = $_GET["email"];
    $line = file_get_contents("/****/********/*****/$username.csv");
    $rows = explode(",", $line);

    print_r ($rows);
    $newrows = trim($rows[6]);
    $newpasskey = trim($passkey);

    if($newrows == $newpasskey)
    {
        echo "Email-Id confirmed.";
        fclose($userdata);
        $userdata = fopen("/****/********/******/$username.csv", "a+");
        fwrite($userdata, ",".$email);
        fclose($userdata);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please specify "it doesn't work"...

Comment: Yeah and can you provide an example of `print_r($rows);`?

Comment: The script doesn't give an output.

Comment: You really should make some treatment to your `$username` variable as it's an user input you are using to browse your directory system.

Comment: Array([0]=>first name[1]=>last name[2]=>male/female[3]=>password(hash)[4]=>dna=>number[5]username[6]=>passkey)

Comment: Then compare with `$rows[5]`, not 6

Comment: I am storing the user info in a file with their username as the name of the file.

Comment: I cannot compare it with 5 as there is one more variable that I missed.

Comment: Well start with looking at what's entered in this comparison: `$rows[6] == $passkey` by doing this: `echo "[{$rows[6]}][$passkey]";`. Next I would always `trim()` both like this: `trim($rows[6]) == trim($passkey)` just to be safe.

Comment: Still it doesn't give an output.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but storing data in csv file is a bad idea. Performance, maintenance, ... so many things that could be improved by using a database... And exporting a database table to CSV is very easy if at some point you need CSV format.

Comment: So `echo "[{$rows[6]}][$passkey]";` just before the comparison doesn't give any output either? Do you just get a blank page? The latter can point to a syntax error in your code.

Comment: I get the output for the print_r($rows); I don't get it for the if statement.

Comment: Ok, so the condition in the if statement is not met. So you need to try to debug this. My suggestion is to put `echo "[{$rows[6]}][$passkey]";` in front of the if statement to see the two things you compare. Perhaps they are not equal?

Comment: Can you COPY the output of `print_r($rows)` to your question, what you posted in the comments is NOT the output of `print_r()`.

Comment: Array ( [0] => "First Name" [1] => "Last Name" [2] => male [3] => " d5b1ee4b463dc7db3b0eaaa0ea2cb5b4" [4] => " 1" [5] => " test123" [6] => " cc03e747a6afbbcbf8be7668acfebee5" )

Comment: Quite unreadable in the comments, but anyways, as you can see, `$rows[6]` contains a space at the beginning, `trim()` your data like everybody suggested and you should be good to go. (If you trimmed your data already, please _EDIT your QUESTION_ and add the new code.)

Comment: I trimmed them and stored them in a separate variable. Still no output.

Comment: I think this is the point where you're on your own again. Good luck with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason.I had made a mistake while entering the user info onto the file. I changed the php script that enters user info to the file. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$passkey = trim($passkey);
$stored_pass = trim($rows[6]);
if($stored_pass == $passkey)
{
  //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Won't work because `$stored` is empty. Also, OP uses `$rows`, not `$row`.

Comment: Thanks @IkoTikashi, I've updated my answer. Typos, or still, I should be more thorough. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at PHPs csv functions to ease loading/writing .csv data.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Also, in your code, make sure that `$username` and `$passkey` are set, trimmed and sanitized before continuing.

You might also want to switch from `GET` to `POST` method in your form, I personally wouldn't want my password to be seen in the URL.

Comment: I tried many alternatives. The password in hashed and the GET method is ,I guess, better because the variables have to be passed on when the user clicks the confirmation link in an email.